# Malicious edits

Tags: bug, editing, user-accounts

I realized that some "anonymous user" suggests malicious edits of questions and answers. The user adds meaningless texts to the posts. I rejected two such edits in my Review quotes.

Could you check where the anonymous user come from and how to block it?

Comment: Since this is a network-wide issue rather than specific to SE.QuantumComputing, it may be productive to ask it on the [main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In this case, I believe this question is specific to QC (? - please correct me if I'm wrong). We have looked into it and there's nothing else we can do, although if they keep trying, an automatic block should be (has been?) applied. I keep meaning to write an answer... but there's just not much else to say as I don't really know much more than you here (well, it was only 2 posts and they haven't tried anything else that I can tell)

Comment: Thanks, we will sebe what happen next. Currently it seems that everything is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few weeks after this, it appears that this was either a random isolated one-off (or mistake) or possibly that the automated block came into force. Which one it is, I don't know but nothing else appears to have happened since.

Just to confirm, if this happens again, either flagging, writing a meta post (or I suppose commenting here), or pinging a mod in chat are all perfectly good ways to get a mod to look at it.